# Ler valores de um bluetooth, numa aplicação react

Tags: arduino, react, bluetooth

Tenho uma aplicação em React e tenho um bluetooth ligado a um arduino. 
Quando envio um valor para o bluetooth, gostaria de o ler na minha aplicação React, mas não estou a encontrar como posso fazer.